# Xcode 7 Project run fails with at linker command failed with exit code 1 Crashlytics

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors, crashlytics

I installed Crashlytics with Cocoapods instead of with their desktop wizard (stupid, I know). I get linker errors and can't build. Messages indicate 212 duplicate files - all other frameworks seems fine. Funny thing is it built the first time to test out Fabric and it ran.

I checked the official fix on their site, but there wasn't really a good answer.

Anyone else experience this and how did you fix?

UPDATE: I also have the Facebook SDK and Parse in the podfile - could this be causing some conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your current project and open the .xcworkspace created in your project folder.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that. I just had to deintegrate and add the frameworks back the manual way for Fabric and with pods for the other ones. Didn't really answer the question but the problem was solved.